# Mock svn instance for testing svnkit tests

Tags: java, tdd, mocking, svnkit

A project I'm working on interacts heavily with Subversion, using svnkit.

Are there any examples on running a mock in-memory svn instance, to help facilitate testing etc?

Cheers

Marty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite straightforward to create a temporary SVN repository on the filesystem to use during the test which you can delete immediately at the end of the test. You would use file:// protocol to access it.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.*;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.*;

public class SVNTest {

    private static final String path = "/tmp/testrepo";
    SVNURL tgtURL;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
        tgtURL = SVNRepositoryFactory.createLocalRepository( new File( path ), true , false );
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(path));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a simple SVN repository with mock data ? It's just a few commands.

Comment: And you could use Runtime.exec(<..>) to execute svnadm within your test class(es)

Comment: The point of using SVNKit is that it provides a much nicer API to SVN than using Runtime.exec()

Answer (score 0):

you may be intested in [mockito](http://mockito.org/), that should work fine with SVNkit

my 0.02$